# Array of unique objects in react native

Tags: react-native

There is a method to store an array of objects for question id as key and answer as a value.

But it is creating multiple objects of same question id because of saving the previous state of object.

```
handleSelect(questionId,index,value){
        this.setState((oldState)=>({selectedOptions:[...oldState.selectedOptions,{question:questionId,answer:value}]}))
    }
```

How can i create unique array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a number of ways - one way might be to use the `Array#reduce()` method like so:

```
handleSelect(questionId,index,value) {

    // Your array containing items with duplicate questions
    const arrayWithDuplicates = [ 
      ...this.state.selectedOptions,
      { question:questionId,answer:value }
    ];

    // Use reduce to create an array of items with unique questions
    const selectedOptions = arrayWithDuplicates
    .reduce((uniqueArray, item) => {

      const isItemInUniqueArray = uniqueArray.find(uniqueItem => {
          return uniqueItem.question === item.question; 
      });

      if(!isItemInUniqueArray) {
          uniqueArray.push(item);
      }

      return uniqueArray

    }, [])

    this.setState((oldState)=>({selectedOptions: selectedOptions}))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but getting an error that oldState is undefined. (oldState in arrayWithDuplicates)

Comment: @game_dev thanks for that, just updated to `this.state.selectedOptions` to correct the issue

Answer (score 1):

This thread is closed now. I got the solution for my problem.

```
handleSelect(questionId,index,value) {
                  let question = this.state.selectedOptions.find((questions) => {
                      return questions.question === questionId
                  });
                    if(question){
                      this.setState(prevState => ({
                      selectedOptions: prevState.selectedOptions.map(
                      obj => (obj.question === questionId ? Object.assign(obj, { answer: value }) : obj)
                    )
                    }));
                    }
                    else{
                      this.setState((oldState)=>({selectedOptions:[...oldState.selectedOptions,{question:questionId,answer:value}]}))
                    }
              }
```